# Probability of server being down, knowing only uptime

Tags: probability, statistics

So I am working on project where I am monitoring server uptime/downtime. I have logs that track server uptime. Basically uptime is checked every 15 minutes. The value is total uptime (so if a server has been up for 45 minutes than that it the value that is recorded). We do not track downtime, but when a server goes down, the value for uptime resets to 0 when the server comes back up.

Here is my problem.

Event 1: uptime= 45 minutes 3:00 PM
Event 2: uptime= 11 minutes 3:15 PM
Event 3: uptime= 3  minutes 3:30 PM
Event 4: uptime= 7  minutes 3:45 PM

That means somewhere between 3:00 and 3:04 the server was down. It could have been 3:01, 3:02, etc. We don't know, all we know is that the server came back up at 3:15.

Now for my question, how do I compute the most probable percent down time? I feel like this is a lot more simpler than I'm making it.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

For calculating the probability it doesn't matter exactly when the server was down, just how long it has been down over a period of time.

There's nothing in your question that allows us to say anything about the length of the downtime, but it has been down at least three times (between each consecutive event), if we assume (rather randomly) that it was down for 1 minute each of those times, it's been down for 3 minutes over a period of 90 minutes (at 3:00 PM it has an uptime of 45 minutes, so it has been up since 2:15 PM), giving a probability of it being down of:
$$
\frac{3}{90}\approx 3.3333333\%
$$

Comment: I appreciate the response!! As you stated, we have no way no know the length of the downtime, this is what makes this problem difficult. I am not looking for the probability of the server being, I am looking for the most probable length of time the server was down. Also, we can not assume that the server went down for 1 minutes. So between Event 1 and 2, the server could have been down either 1,2,3 or 4 minutes. Looking at all four events, whats the most probable length of time the servers were down. Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your example server seems to be down quite often. If we assume the downtime is always mostly the same $t$ minutes (or at least has an expected value of $t$ minutes) and it is extremely unlikely to have two down events within the same 15 minute window (this might be doubtful with your example data, but should be tur for a real-life scenario) then the first uptime measurements (i.e., uptime reports below 15 minutes) should have an expected value of $\frac{15-t}2$. Observing sufficiently many such events may give an estimation for $t$. However, this requires many observations especially if $t$ is small.

On the other hand, if $t$ is not very small compared to the 15 minute window, you may occasionally observe it down during your periodic probing, which may help with the statistics (e.g., if the downtime is typically 5 minutes, about one out of three events should lead to a failed probing).

Nothing of this helps with the *individual* events (apart from the obvious upper bounds from the preceding known-good probing). I would generally recommend a technical over a mathematical approach here: As the downtime seems to be related to server restarts (as opposed to, say, network interruptions), there *should* be suitable info findable in the server logs, either e.g. web server access log entries that are generated much more often than your 15 minute probings or even explicit messages a la "System going down for reboot". In fact, if there is no log entry about the system going down because the downtime occurs due to unexpected outages, you should rather investigate the causes than try to measure/guess the lengths of downtime. For embedded systems without much logging capacity, snmp traps might be used for similar purpose.

Comment: My example is server is down often because I wanted you to understand what the data looks like. I will be looking at data for 30 days, uptime is recorded every 15-30 minutes. As for your assumptions, we can not assume the first one. We must assume that the server can be down for any amount of time and can be vary greatly. Your second assumption is correct. We assume that the server can only do down once within the 15 minute window because there is no way for us to know if it went down more than once. Thank you very much!

Comment: @muhqa Even if the individual downtimes vary as a random variable, that will still have an expected value.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what your saying now. Unfortunately, the only information I have is what I described to you in my original post. I will simply estimate t and use the method you described. I appreciate the help!